# wrong background color for subsequent frame creating a GIF

Tags: python-imaging-library, gif, animated-gif

I'm trying to resize a gif in a smaller version.
this is what i come up with at the moment:

```
from PIL import Image

def process_gif(in_path, out_path= 'out.gif', size= (32,32)):
    with Image.open(in_path) as im :
        images = []
        durations = []
        for i in range(im.n_frames - 1, -1, -1):
            im.seek(i)
            im.thumbnail(size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS) # noqa
            im_temp = im.copy()
            images.insert(0, im_temp)
            durations.append(im.info['duration'])
        images[0].save(
            out_path,
            format='gif',
            interlace=True,
            save_all=True,
            append_images=images[1 :],
            loop=0,
            duration=durations,
            disposal=2,
            background=(255,255,255,255),
            optimize=False
        )
```

when i try to create the gif the first frame have the correct background and the rest have isssue.
with this gif as imput [in.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHo1J.gif)
i get those frame in the `images` before saving: [0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X57Wq.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI5by.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2aCU.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAGxB.png)
and this is the output [out.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0AoH.gif)

spent some time figuring out where is the error with no clue, the output should have trasparent background in every frame of the GIF

P.S. i noticed imgur colored the trasparent frame, the in.gif, 0, 1, 2, 3 all have trasparent background, open with your image viewer should let you see better

After some other attemp i looked for trasparency doing `print(im_temp.info)` before inserting the resized image, NOTE that the cycle it's backward to solve another issue so it's last frame to first frame

```
{'version': b'GIF89a', 'background': 0, 'loop': 0, 'duration': 70}
{'version': b'GIF89a', 'background': 0, 'loop': 0, 'duration': 70}
{'version': b'GIF89a', 'background': 0, 'loop': 0, 'duration': 70}
{'version': b'GIF89a', 'background': 0, 'loop': 0, 'duration': 70, 'transparency': 48, 'extension': (b'NETSCAPE2.0', 219)}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import GifImagePlugin
GifImagePlugin.LOADING_STRATEGY = GifImagePlugin.LoadingStrategy.RGB_AFTER_DIFFERENT_PALETTE_ONLY
```

using this solved my problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).